# Elasticsearch date formatting in x axis

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I ingest the data in following format to elasticsearch:

```
    Date         Region          KPI
    2019/7       ON              257
    2019/8       ON              885
    2019/9       ON              663
```

When I create a line chart in Kibana, I could not format the date in x axis (Image added). I also tried changing the dateFormat in advanced setting to "YYYY-MM" but still x axis displays yyyy-mm-dd.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is using `dateFormat:scaled` from the settings for that. You can change this in Settings -> Advanced Settings, the default value is:

```
[
  ["", "HH:mm:ss.SSS"],
  ["PT1S", "HH:mm:ss"],
  ["PT1M", "HH:mm"],
  ["PT1H", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"],
  ["P1DT", "YYYY-MM-DD"],
  ["P1YT", "YYYY"]
]
```

Depending on the "Minimum interval" for "Date Histogram", you need to add/change different values. For example, for "Monthly" interval you need to add the following:

```
  ["P1MT", "YYYY-MM"],
```